# Adding variable amount of arrays to a new String array

Tags: android, arrays, expandablelistview

I am creating an expandablelistview in android. I have an sql database with each item having a "group name" (of which there is a number of items with the same group name) and then a unique "filename" which becomes my groups in my expandablelistview and my children, respectively.

I want to try and create an expandablelistview that runs through and adds the required groups and children based off code, so that I can add new groups and also new files to the existing groups and it will not need recoding.

Here is what I have so far:

```
String[] groups;
arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

Cursor listCursor = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"groupname"}, null, null, "groupname", null, null, null);
listCursor.moveToFirst();
if (!listCursor.isAfterLast()) {
do {
    nametoadd = listCursor.getString(0);
    arraylist.add(nametoadd);
    } while (listCursor.moveToNext());
}
listCursor.close();
groups = arraylist.toArray(new String[arraylist.size()]);
```

As you can see it creates a Cursor query, which looks for distinct values in the groupname column and then adds each of those to the arraylist. Then the groups adds that arraylist and that works correctly, and i can get my variable amount of groups. I am having trouble with adding the children.

My existing code adds the children in the following way:

```
private String[][] children = {
            { "child item1", "child item2", "child item3" },
            { "child item1", "child item2", "child item3" } 
};
```

The problem here is that first, I will have a variable amount of items in each array, and second I will have a variable amount of arrays in the children array.

I have a solution for the first part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
        listCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"groupname", "description"}, "groupname='"+arraylist.get(i)+"'", null, null, null, null);
        listCursor.moveToFirst();
        if (!listCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                nametoadd = listCursor.getString(1);
                arraylist.add(nametoadd);
            } while (listCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        listCursor.close();
        childrenlist = arraylist.toArray(new String[arraylist.size()]);

    }
```

This adds whatever child items are in each groupname. But then how can I add each array to the children array?

Answer (score 0):

create a class for the children. Say

```
 Class Children{
     public ArrayList<String> content;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a solution that works:

I created:

```
private List<String[]> childList;
```

and then added:

```
childList.add(childrenlist);
```

in the second loop.

Final code is:

```
arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

Cursor listCursor = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"groupname"}, null, null, "groupname", null, null, null);
listCursor.moveToFirst();
if (!listCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    do {
    nametoadd = listCursor.getString(0);
    arraylist.add(nametoadd);
} while (listCursor.moveToNext());
}
listCursor.close();
groups = arraylist.toArray(new String[arraylist.size()]);

arraylist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
childList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
listCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"groupname", "description"}, "groupname='"+arraylist.get(i)+"'", null, null, null, null);
listCursor.moveToFirst();
if (!listCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    do {
    nametoadd = listCursor.getString(1);
    arraylist1.add(nametoadd);
    } while (listCursor.moveToNext());
}
listCursor.close();
childrenlist = arraylist1.toArray(new String[arraylist1.size()]);       
childList.add(childrenlist);
arraylist1.clear();
}
```

And then i can reference the items in the childlist by:

```
childList.get(groupPosition)[childPosition]
```